# postprocessing GPS coordinates with RINEX data to improve precision?

Tags: data, gps, openstreetmap, rinex

Im doing some mapping for OSM in my region and I am curious if the precision of tracks from a GPS Receiver can be improved if they are post processed with RINEX data.

The tracking is done with a Garmin GPSMAP 60CSX or alternatively my Android Phone and OSMTracker for Android.

The RINEX data is available from http://igs.bkg.bund.de/filestatus/dailyrinex

cheerio
   steve

Comment: what restrictions are with the RINEX data? OSM prefers first hand gps traces, corrections are usually after the upload to osm server. 'Many hands make light work'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To perform post-processing you typically need a GPS that can record raw pseudorange and carrier cycle data.  Very few consumer level GPS support this functionality, and those that do require software modification.  I am not sure about android, most likely it would depend on the GPS chip that the phone is using.

Comment: Could you say which ones _do_ support this?

Comment: None that I know of.  According to [this](http://www.gpspassion.com/forumsen/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=55795#381869) SiRFII based receivers did record some additional data.  Some [references](http://bluelog.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/bluelog/doc/BlueLoggerReference.pdf?revision=1.1) exist to the Delorme Blue Logger also having some [rinex ability](http://www.gpsnuts.com/mygps/gps/hardware%20reviews/Earthmate/earthmate.htm), but not sure if this is still correct or officially supported.  I would love to find a cheap device that supports RINEX.

Answer (score 2):

Trimble produces a [GPS Analyst extensi](http://www.trimble.com/mappingGIS/gpsanalyst.aspx)on for ArcGIS which can perform post-processing with RINEX data. On the open source side, it looks like [GPSTk](http://www.gpstk.org/bin/view/Documentation/WebHome) can be used.

Answer (score 1):

This article lists Android devices that support raw GNSS measurements: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/gnss.html

Answer (score 1):

A few year later and there are now options that are not too expensive to get raw pseudorange measurements in RINEX format. The Garmin GPSMAP 66s line of receivers ($400-$500) can record to a RINEX file. And on the more electronics hobbyist side the ublox F9P modules can be had for $200-$300 https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15136

I haven't done much with the opensource software for dynamic processing, but have done several CORS OPUS processed static points to get cm level accurate locations of features visible in aerial imagery, which allows me to understand how well aligned the maps are in different localities.